# How to embed panels (description) from a Twitch channel on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, iframe, twitch

So I'm making a web view where I'm trying to add all informations about a Twitch channel.

I succeeded to add the video and chat using iframes but now I want to add the panels (or description) of the corresponding channel.
[Here is an example of pannels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CLKo.jpg).

Is there a way to get those panels and add them into my page ?

Thanks,

Comment: Twitch has an [API](https://dev.twitch.tv/) which may be helpful

Comment: I know but I didn't found what I wanted on it :(

Comment: With the new Twitch API you can [Get Users](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-users) which will return their channel description but not their custom panels. You could attempt to do some sort of page scraping to get those panels.

Comment: I tried to do an iframe directly on the Twitch channel but it didn't display anything as if Twitch was blocking iframes exept those for video and chat..

Comment: Cross site domain issues could prevent if they do not specifically permit it